# Understanding final values of Java tracing table given informal contract

Tags: java, trace, loop-invariant

I am currently in an introductory programming class and was asked to interpret the final state of the given tracing table featuring a loop invariant. The blue numbers in the bottom box are the given answers.

As you can see, low is updated but I don't know how this number was achieved given the information in the contract.

[Tracing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNsGp.png)

Edit: Is a correct method to solving this finding the "boundary" values where the expressions in the **@maintains** clause hold true?

Since **n** doesn't change, **high** at the least can be 81, and **low** at the greatest is 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this would be confusing if you didn't understand the full definition of the loop invariant, like I did.

A **loop invariant** is a conditional statement that is true at the beginning of the method, before and after each iteration, and at the end of the method. Otherwise, it is not a valid loop invariant.

Knowing variables **low** and **high** are updated, we know their values have a chance of being changed in the method. **n**, on the other hand, will remain the same.

The loop invariants are **low * low <= high** and **low * low <= n <= high**. These must hold true at the end of the method body.

The loop only runs when **low * low < high**, i.e., the loop stops once **low * low >= high**. But, **low * low > high** cannot happen due to our loop invariant (equals-to symbol omitted for clarity)!

So following the rule that the loop invariant must hold, and knowing when the while loop stops, it's concluded that the final values must be:

**low * low = high**.

Factor in **n** and we have **low * low = n = high**. Again, we know **low** and **high** are the only values that have a chance of being changed.

Finally, we have **low * low = 81 = high**.

low = 9, n = 81, high = 81.